# My python script works in IDLE but not in console

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code executes properly in IDLE but return an error in console.

```
import sys, math, string, time, os
from time import *
restart0 = True
while restart0:
    def addDecimal():
        print(".", end="\r")
    breakout0 = False
    invalidcommand0 = True
    while invalidcommand0:
        file = open("HighScores.txt","r+")
        sleep(0.5)
        print("\nWelcome to VACSecureServers™\n")
        start = input("Would you like to start the program? ")
        if start.lower() == "yes":
            print("\n1. Display high scores\n2. Add a new high score\n3. Clear all high scores\n4. Quit")
            option = input()
            if option == "1":
                print (file.read())
                if os.stat("highscores.txt").st_size==0:
                    print("There are no highscores currently in the system, please return and input some.")
            elif option == "2":
                numberAppend = int(input("How many scores would you likes to add to the program? "))
                for loop in range(numberAppend):
                    name = input("Enter the name of the user:" )
                    score = input("Enter a score: ")
                    file.write(name+","+score+","+strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S\n"))
            elif option == "3":
                open("HighScores.txt", 'w').close()
                print("Highscores resetting")
                sleep(0.4)
                addDecimal()
                sleep(0.6)
                addDecimal()
                sleep(0.9)
                addDecimal()
                sleep(1.2)
                print("Successfully reset!")
                sleep(2)
            elif option == "4":
                sys.exit()
        file.close()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\script.py", line 12, in <module>
  print("\nWelcome to VACSecureServers™\n")
 File: "C:\Python3\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
  return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2122' in position 29: character maps to <undefined>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What goes wrong? And can you lay out the code so I it is valid and I can read it? Thanks

Comment: I did lay it out I'm just new to stackoverflow so I didn't know I had to use a code sample to paste it in.

Comment: You might want to replace all this gibberish with an actual description of your problem. Also,  indenting code in the post by 4 white spaces will enable colouration.

Comment: You need to say what "it doesn't work" means. What do you see? What error do you get? There's a *reason* SO forces you to write text as well as code, and that is so that we have a remote chance of actually understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this line

```
print("\nWelcome to VACSecureServers™\n")
```

You have a `™` symbol in it. Your console probably can't display it, but IDLE supports unicode characters. Remove it and your code should work just fine.